# Fourier transform of cosine with square root

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions

In relativistic mechanics, i came across the Fourier transform of the following function : $\cos \left(t \sqrt{x^2+m^2} \right)$ or $e^{it \sqrt{x^2+m^2}}$ ($t$ and $m$ are constants).
Is there a way to express the Fourier transform of these functions using special functions ?

Comment: If i remember correctly this related with Bessel functions

Comment: I also remember seeing something with Bessel functions but Wikipedia does not list it and Wolfram Alpha does not give any answer

Comment: you may have a look into Courant&Hilbert, i think you can find something there...

Comment: You can approximate it using the principal of stationary phase if it oscillates enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related. The function
$$
   f(a,b,x)=\frac{\sin[b\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}]}{\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}
$$
has Fourier transform
$$
       \hat{f}(a,b,s)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                  \frac{\pi}{2}J_{0}[a\sqrt{b^{2}-s^{2}}], & 0 < s < b \\
                  0 & b < s < \infty
               \end{array}\right.
$$
The derivative of $f$ with respect to $b$ is $\cos[b\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}]$, and that should be related to the derivative of $\hat{f}$ with respect to $b$.

**Reference:** Harry Batemen,  *Table of Integral Transforms, Vol I*, pg. 26 (section 1.7)
[image]

Comment: I just checked in the book you refer to and all formulas are given for $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ argument in the sine function and not $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$

Comment: @Mirajane : Page 26, Section 1.7. I added a scan for you. I listed the wrong page in the post--it is page 26 and not 27. Look at (30).

Comment: You are right, sorry for my mistake. When i take the derivative in $b$, i get a $J_1(...)$ term, should i add a Dirac delta accounting for the discontinuity in $b$?

Comment: @Mirajane : It's a little hard to account for, isn't it? I'd have to think about that, and would probably try to put it into the context where you need it, and then look at it.

Comment: here is my problem : i want to solve the PDE $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \phi(t,x)-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \phi(t,x) + m^2 \phi(t,x)=0$ (wave equation with mass term) with initial conditions $\phi(0,x)=\delta(x)$ (Dirac delta) and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(0,x)=0$. I found that the solution could be written as $\phi(t,x)=\int \frac{1}{2\pi} \cos (t \sqrt{m^2+p^2})e^{ipx} dp$ (regardless of convergence problems). Using your result, i evaluate this as: $1/2 (\delta(x-t)+\delta(x+t))-\frac{mt}{2\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}J_1[m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}]$ only on $-t<x<t$

Comment: It looks strange but it could be the result...

Comment: @Mirajane : The connection with the known transform would come by integrating in $t$ over some interval and checking agreement. Very interesting.

Comment: After checking the above function, it seems to me that the $J_1$ part does satisfy the PDE but not the Dirac deltas... Either there is a mistake in my Fourier computation either my differentiation is wrong ; these deltas are tricky ! Thank you for your help & comments anyway !

Comment: @Mirajane : If you know $\phi(t,x)$ is as stated, then look at $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\phi(t,x)dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \frac{\sin(t_2\sqrt{m^{2}+p^{2}})}{\sqrt{m^{2}+p^{2}}}-\frac{\sin(t_1\sqrt{m^{2}+p^{2}})}{\sqrt{m^{2}+p^{2}}}e^{ipx}dp$. Evaluate the right side and then differentiate with respect to $t_2$ to get back to your original problem. See what you get.