# Why is this integral $0$ when $x > t$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider the integral

$$
I \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}} \sin(t \sqrt{p^2 + m^2} ) e^{i p x}.
$$
It appears to me that when $x > 0$ and $x > t$ the above integral is $0$. First, rewrite it as
$$
I = \frac{i}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}} (e^{-it\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}} - e^{it\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}}) e^{i p x}.
$$

Now consider deforming the $p$ integral on the complex plane. If $p$ has a large positive imaginary part, then the integrand goes to zero as long as $x > t$. Because the integrand has no poles, this allows us to close the contour with a semi circle in the upper half plane. Because there are no poles, this integral is then $0$.

I am not asking for a rigorous proof of why $I = 0$ when $x > t$ using complex analysis, because I think the proof I sketched above is right. What does confuse me is that, from its definition, nothing special appears to happen to $I$ when $x$ goes from being less than $t$ to being greater than $t$. What am I looking for is a satisfying explanation for why the value of this integral changes dramatically in the $x > t$ and the $x < t$ cases, just by using the properties of the $p$ integral along the real axis.

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with the fact that $\mathcal{F}[\sin(x)/x]$ is a box function.

Comment: Are you assuming $t\ge0$?

Comment: Yes, $x>0$ and $t > 0$

Comment: @user1379857, in that case it would suffice to say $x\gt t\gt0$ (but $|x|\gt|t|$ might be better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's use the symmetry of the integrand to remove the complex exponential
\begin{multline}
I = 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(t\sqrt{p^2+m^2}\right)}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\cos\left(xp\right)dp \\ = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(xp+t\sqrt{p^2+m^2}\right)}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}dp+\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(t\sqrt{p^2+m^2}- xp\right)}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}dp \\ 
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(xp + t\sqrt{p^2+m^2})}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}dp
\end{multline}
Now, let's look at the argument of that sine function. If $|x| > |t|$, then it's a monotonic function. We can make a simple substitution $u = xp + t\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$, and doing the algebra gives
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt{u^2+m^2(x^2-t^2)}} = 0,
$$
since the integrand is odd.

On the other hand, if $|t| > |x|$, the argument of the sine function is not monotonic. It achieves a minimum at $p_0 = -mx/\sqrt{t^2-x^2}$ with value $u_0 = m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}$. So we have to split the integral at $p_0$, then do the substitution $u = xp + t\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$. The algebra ends up being the same as before, but because of the different limits of integration, you get
$$
I = 2\int_{m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt{u^2-m^2(t^2-x^2)}} = \pi J_0\left(m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}\right)
$$
where $J_0$ is a Bessel function.

Answer (score 1):

If we define the Fourier transform of a function  and its inverse as
$$\mathcal F(f)(\omega)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx \,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\, f(x)=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R} \mathcal F(f)(\omega)e^{jx\omega}d\omega$$

Then, what you're looking for the inverse Fourier transform of $$g(\omega)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\omega^2 + m^2}} \sin(t \sqrt{\omega^2 + m^2} )$$

It turns out that function has a compact support, more precisely its support is $[-|t|, |t|]$. Indeed, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336434/fourier-transform-of-cosine-with-square-root), the inverse Fourier transform of $g$ is 
$$f(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                  CJ_{0}\left(m\sqrt{t^{2}-x^{2}}\right) & \text{ if } 0 < |x| < |t| \\
                  0 & \text{ if } |t| < |x| < +\infty
               \end{array}\right.$$
Where $C$ is a constant and $J_0$ is the first [Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1).